# Opening HDF files using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modis, ndvi, hdf

I downloaded from the USGS Earth Explorer a MODIS Landsurface Reflectance V6 MODIS MOD09Q1 V6 image to calculate an NDVI. I'm trying to open it on ArcGIS Pro, however when I import the file, the Subdataset Selection dialog box does not open and the hdf files appears as a time serieS.

Does anyone know how to properly open this file or how can I open the Subdataset Selection dialog box?

Answer (score 3):

Use the toolbox:  Data Management --> Raster --> Raster Processing --> Extract Subdataset